# Which button state is triggered when you long-click (highlight) the cell in which it exists?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton, ios-3.x

I have a custom table view cell view that contains a button. I initialize the button to `setBackgroundImage` to an empty circle in its normal state. I also `setImage` to a checkmark image for its selected state.

```
    checkmarkButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(kLeftMargin, kTopMargin, kButtonSize, kButtonSize)];
    [checkmarkButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"empty-circle.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [checkmarkButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkmark.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [checkmarkButton addTarget:self action:@selector(checkmarkButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.contentView addSubview:checkmarkButton];
```

When the button is clicked on, I set the button as selected and told to redraw so that the button looks like a circle with a checkmark in it. Click on it again and `selected` is set to `NO` and the cell is told to redraw so that it's an empty circle.

```
- (void)checkmarkButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [checkmarkButton setSelected:!checkmarkButton.selected];

    [managedObjectContext save:nil];
}
```

My problem is that this button exists in a custom table view cell view, which seems to control how it's drawn in a way that I can't identify. When I long-click (touch down in the cell and staying in the cell without touching up for a while) on a cell whose button is set selected (should display a checkmark in a circle), the checkmark disappears until I touch up. When I touch up, the state of the cell is correct. It's just wrong while I am long-clicking the cell.

So, how do I control how that button is drawn when I long-click on the cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly your case because I didn't see your sources. But please check the `Highlighted` state of your button. When `UIButton` is placed on `UITableViewCell` then table controls your UIButton: on cell touch down (long touch) `UIButton` as well as `UITableViewCell` change its state to `Highlighted` and returns to `Default` or `Selected` state on touch up.

UPDATE:
I agree it is unexpected behavior. You can create subclass of UIButton and reimplement this call to leave it empty to prevent calling super method:

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted;
```

Example:

```
@interface XButton : UIButton
@end

@implementation XButton
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted { }
@end
```

This should prevent state changing by table.

Comment: I've added possible solution. Please try.

Answer (score 0):

when you click and hold a button the state that is getting called is the highlighted state, thus when you release the click the state returns to UIControlStateNormal

Comment: I would assume so to. This highlighted state is called `UIControlStateHighlighted`

Comment: Thanks Kquane, but the question is not "what happens when I long-click on a button?", but "what happens when I long-click on the _parent_ of a button?"